# What is the simplest way to transfer webform /data/ from one instance to another?

Tags: webforms, importing-exporting

I have much webform data that I want to move from a data entry instance to a testing instance, but I don't want the entire database.  What is a simple recipe for exporting and importing drupal webform data.

I know about the webform export / webform import modules, and the import module that this is possible, but I can't find the correct combination of parameters that makes it happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is possible to export/import only selected tables on testing environments (not recommended on production sites).

A simple way is to use backup&migrate module (https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) and then export and import the webform tables you like. You can select this tables on the advanced options.

Comment: If you go to "**Advanced backup**", and scroll to the tab "**default database backup options**" you'll find the option to *exclude the following tables* altogether.

Select all of them, except `webform_submissions` and `webform_submitted_data`. Download it, and *restore* that file to your other installation (using Backup & Migrate there as well).